# How remove custom style with select

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with select styling. I use bootstrap.
I want to remove the style from the selected option

[image]

How to remove this gray background? I want to it be blue.

This is my html code

```
   <select multiple id="select" name="price" class="form-control currency-selector">
       <option value="$10000-$15000">$10 000 - $15 000</option>
        <option value="$15 000 - $30 000">$15 000 - $30 000</option>
        <option value="$30 000 - $50 000">$30 000 - $50 000</option>
        <option value="$50 000+">$50 000+</option>
     </select>

.currency-selector {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: $input-border-width solid $input-border-color;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: $logan;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.625rem;

  option {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show some of your code relating to this question

Comment: as @SASSY_ROG said if you can show some code related to this post then it will be easier to us to help,as it looks like simple one

Comment: Please show your CSS codes

Comment: @Viduthalai I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below CSS :

```
select#select option{
background: blue;}
```

and change the hover color of option you can use below CSS:

```
    select#select option:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px blue inset;}
```